# How to download a file using http package?

Tags: http, tcl

How to download a file using `http` package?

```
package require http
set file  [ ::http::geturl "<url>"]
```

Something simillar to what curl does:

```
curl -X GET '<URL>' -o /tmp/download.tar
```

My requirement is I am having a file on a linux server X & from another linux server Y where I have my `http` package installed along with Tcl. Now can some one suggest on how to download that file from X & save it in Y?

Answer (score 3):

If you read the [documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/http.htm#M13), you see that if you pass the `-channel` option, the `http::geturl` command will write the data from the URL to that channel. It does this efficiently. In addition, if you pass the `-binary` flag you can force there to be no interpretation of the bytes. These are the tools you need.

However, you should also know that the return value from `http::geturl` is a “token”, which is used in further commands, e.g., to query whether the GET was successful. It should be cleaned up when you're done.

Here's an example with very little error detection.

```
set f [open /tmp/download.tar wb]
set tok [http::geturl $URL -channel $f -binary 1]
close $f
if {[http::status $tok] eq "ok" && [http::ncode $tok] == 200} {
    puts "Downloaded successfully"
}
http::cleanup $tok
```

There's a great many things that can go wrong!

Answer (score 2):

If you had searched for "tcl http download file" you would have found [this page](http://wiki.tcl-lang.org/8575), which has this code:

```
package require http
proc getPage { url } {
    set token [::http::geturl $url]
    set data [::http::data $token]
    ::http::cleanup $token          
    return $data
}
```

The command is named `getPage`, but it will get most files for you. It will not handle binary files correctly, but if you search some more, or look at the documentation, you will find out how to deal with those.

Comment: Thanks guys, these helped me a lot :-)